# JRadioButton e JButton

Tags: java

Boa tarde pessoal!
Senhores, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação pequena, que é um conversor de arquivos para uso próprio aqui na empresa e me deparo com uma dúvida que pode parecer besta, mas não encontrei uma resposta satisfatória ainda. É o seguinte: Possuo a seguinte telinha:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: Eu coloquei logs nesses radios, pra toda vez que alguns deles forem executados, ele imprimir uma linha com seu respectivo nome. Só que eu quero que eles sejam executados APENAS quando o botão "Iniciar" for precionado. Minha dúvida é, pra isso acontecer, tenho que chamar o metodo

```
radioApagarInicioLinha.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //codigo aqui
        }
    });
```

Ou se eu simplesmente colocar um

```
if (radioApagarInicioLinha.isSelected() == true) {
    System.out.println("Clicou!");
}
```

se ele vai executar da mesma forma quando eu clicar no botão?
Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 2):

Com certeza, a segunda maneira é a melhor forma de usar. Se você só precisa validar quando o usuário clicar no botão, não é necessário usar o evento no *Radio Button*.